# How to cast hex string into int in python without conversion

Tags: python, hex

I would like to convert a hex string to be an int but without the value changing.

For example

```
>>> int_value = 0xb19bc74cf4 
>>> print type(int_value)
<type 'int'>
```

Now i have a string

```
>>> str_value = "0xb19bc74cf4"
>>> print type(str_value)
<type 'str'>
```

How do i now convert str_value to be an int_value?

Desired value outcome would be:

```
input: str_value = "0xb19bc74cf4"
Output: int_value = 0xb19bc74cf4
Print of int_value to be 0xb19bc74cf4
print of type(int_value) to be <type 'int'>
```

Comment: How about `int(str_value, 16)`?

Comment: What do you mean with "without conversion" and "without the value changing"?

Comment: That's right @StefanPochmann - I do not want it to be converted in a number, it should remain as a hex value but as type int.

Comment: @ShadiAlmosri Huh? You don't make any sense.

Comment: @ShadiAlmosri Please show the desired value.

Comment: @StefanPochmann - input and output added

Comment: @ShadiAlmosri That doesn't work. Ints don't get printed in hex. Don't ask XY questions.

Comment: @ShadiAlmosri No they don't. If you print ZdaR's `num`, you will **not** see `0xb19bc74cf4`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to realize that an `int` is internally a binary value.  There is no way to "remain as a hex value but as type int". `print` converts it back to a string for display, and you can use `format` to customize the conversion:

```
>>> str_value = '0xb19bc74cf4'
>>> str_value
'0xb19bc74cf4'
>>> n = int(str_value,16)
>>> print(n) # default is to print in base 10
762822741236
>>> print(format(n,'#x')) # format in base 16 with "0x" prepended.
0xb19bc74cf4
```